# How can python extract a hash fragment from a URL?

Tags: javascript, python, api, flask, spotify

I am using Spotify's API to build a python flask app. The user authentication part of Spotify's API concatenates the app id (client_id), scopes, etc. to the end Spotify base url: https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize? (following this would be something like client_id=94857&scope=read). That URL redirects the user to the auth page where they can approve my app to access their Spotify data (meaning now the API should be able to send requests). After they approve, they are taken to redirect URL (which the owner of the Spotify API user (me) inputs into the app's settings) and following the redirect URL is a variable called "access_token" which is a "hash fragment". I need this access_token to be able to make calls to the API because it is a required parameter custom to the user, but I can't access it because a '#' precedes it. The url looks something like this:

https://myRedirectURL.com/callback#access_token=NwAExz...BV3O2Tk&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&state=123

I am able to access all parts of this url from my python functions EXCEPT the info including and following the '#' character, which is the info I need, because it does not have access. I read on another Stackoverflow post that the backend is not able to access hash fragments.

I could have the user manually copy the entire URL or just the access token and input it to my app so it has the data, but I'd like to avoid this and automate the process for the user by having the app extract it and not make it a two-step, input process.

My ideas to obtain this info are to run a javascript function from python at that point when the user is at the URL because javascript react may be able to access the full URL. I'm not sure how to do this and was also wondering if there are other ideas for obtaining the access_token portion of the URL? Please let me know if any other information could be helpful.

Here is the Spotify API Auth doc:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

EDIT:
Thank you for the idea to use the 'Authorization Code Flow' instead of the 'Implicit Grant' flow! This seems like the way to go. The difference seems to me to use a request method and to specify the response_type as "code" so it doesn't come back as a hash. However, it's still not working (I get 'couldn't parse' because the URL still has a '#' in it). I'm suspecting I did specify the parameters in the way it wanted, but I've combed through it and don't see anything. Anything standing out?:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, redirect, url_for
import requests
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

CLIENT_ID = "myclientid"
REDIRECR_URI="http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback" #this is the uri specified in my Spotify app

SCOPE='user-read-private%20user-read-playback-state%20user-top-read'
API_ENDPOINT = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"

PARAMS = {  "client_id": CLIENT_ID, 
            "response_type": 'code', 
            "redirect_uri": REDIRECR_URI,
            "state": '123',
            "scope": SCOPE,
            "show_dialog": False
}
def userAuthURLBuilder(client_id, redirect_uri, scope):
    return "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id={}&redirect_uri={}&scope={}&response_type=token&state=123".format(client_id, redirect_uri, scope)

builtUrl = userAuthURLBuilder(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECR_URI, SCOPE)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def getTester():
    r = requests.get(url = API_ENDPOINT, params=PARAMS)
    data = r.json()
    return data

@app.route('/<path:text>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def all_routes(text):
    if text.startswith('callback'):
        try:
            params = text.split('&code=')[1]
            return params
        except:
            return "couldn't parse" #this is what I'm currently getting 
    else:
        return "it errored"
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you apply some [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Comment: You seem to have initiated the wrong OAuth flow type. Show us the code that generated the URL which leads the user to Spotify.

Comment: @KlausD Thanks so much for the pointing that out. I'm going with the "Authorization Code Flow' now and I posted the code I'm using. Do you have some ideas that may be leading to the errors?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use Spotify's [Implicit Grant Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow), but this is probably not what you want. As it says in the docs:

> Implicit grant flow is for clients that are implemented entirely using JavaScript and running in the resource owner’s browser.

URL hash values are not accessible on the server side - they're not included in the headers. The only way to obtain a URL hash value is from the client - using modern JavaScript you could get this with [`url.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash).

However, what you really should do is use Spotify's [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow). This will send the code as a query parameter instead of behind a hash, and you can get it with [`request.args['code']`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args)

**UPDATE**

In response to your updated question, you should use `request.args` to get the URL query args rather than try to parse out the actual string. Something like this should work:

```py
@app.route('/callback', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def all_routes(text):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    try:
      params = request.args
      if params and params['code']:
        return params['code']
      else:
        return params['error']
    except:
      return "couldn't parse"
  else:
    # not sure why you would use POST here
    return
```

Comment: Thank so much Hugh! I tried your suggestions and edited my question with the code, but it's still not working enough to allow me to experiment with trying the request.args['code'] method because the URL / what I get back as the get response couldn't parse it. I may be doing this incorrectly?

Comment: I updated my answer since I can't get code examples to display usefully in a comment.